# Eclipse shows "/s" as "/W" without quotes

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just freshly installed Eclipse with the Java EE option. Now, When ever I have a lower case 's' following a forward slash, e.g. "/s", Eclipse automatically changes it into capital W, showing "/W".

However, Eclipse compiles it as a lowercase 's', and when the code is copy pasted into, say, Notepad, it will turn back into 's'.

Pressing space, tab, escape is futile. Even if I copy and paste a lower case 's' after a '/', it will still show "/W". There is no way for Eclipse to display the characters '/' and 's' consecutively anywhere even in block or in-line comments. Please! Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Sample code shown in my Eclipse editor:

```
/*
 * This code is used to demonstrate the problem my Eclipse has, which
 * is that "/ s" (without space) is always turned into "/W", even in
 * comments.
 * The code compiles correctly in my Eclipse, showing 0.5 as output in
 * the console.
 */

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double s = 2.0;
        double l = 1.0;
        // Calculate the value of l/W
        System.out.println(l/W); 
    }
}
```

Comment: how bizarre http://s16.postimg.org/9mfa87p6d/Screenshot_38.png

Comment: i never seen this before i know that the forward '/' is not part of escape character. how does it switch to variable that you have not even defined.

Comment: +user3659052 I know right?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was caused by my font smoothing software gdipp. The problem was fixed after uninstalling it for some reason.